# Any python script to convert a geoPDF to a KML embedded with a jpg link?

Tags: python, kml, pdf

I have many geoPDFs. I want to turn them into KMZ or KML+JPEG using a python script.

Any suggestions?

SEE CODE BELOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a script available, but you could probably write one using the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) library. GDAL has input support for geoPDF and output support for JPEG. You would need OGR for the KML output (http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html).

Answer (score 2):

This code below may help guide some one wanting to convert many geoPDFs to KML-Superoverlay which can then be incorporated as web map overlays using Google Maps API or Google Earth API...

```
import shlex
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os


def step1_translate( input_file ):
    out = input_file + ".vrt"
    translate_command = "gdal_translate -of VRT %s %s" % (input_file,out)
    translate_args = shlex.split( translate_command )
    p1 = subprocess.Popen( translate_args) # translate
    print p1

def step2_warp( input_file):
    gdalwarp_command = "gdalwarp -of VRT -t_srs EPSG:4326 %s %s" % (output_file,output_file2)
    gdalwarp_args = shlex.split( gdalwarp_command )
    p2 = subprocess.Popen( gdalwarp_args   , stdin=p1.stdout ) #gdalwarp

def step3_tile( input_file, output_file, output_file2 ):
    gdal2tiles_command = "/home/boris/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal2tiles.py -p geodetic -k %s" % output_file2
    gdal2tiles_args = shlex.split( gdal2tiles_command )
    p3 = subprocess.Popen( gdal2tiles_args , stdin=p2.stdout) #gdal2tiles
```